# Grouping by partial value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I'm very new to SQL and I have no clue how to even begin with this one.
I've got two tables: Warehouse and Items. Here's how they look like(simplified):

**Warehouse**

```
ItemID | QuantityInStock | QuantityOnOrder | QuantityOnOrder2 | QuantityOnOrder3 | QuantityOnOrder4
-------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------
1111   |               8 |               1 |                0 |                1 |               0 
2222   |               3 |               0 |                0 |                0 |               0 
3333   |               4 |               0 |                1 |                0 |               0
```

**Items**

```
ItemID | Code
-------+-----------------
  1111 | abc123456-111-01
  2222 | abc123456-111-02
  3333 | abc123457-112-01
```

What I need to return via SQL query is this:

```
ShortCode | Quantity
----------+---------
abc123456 | 9
abc123457 | 3
```

- ItemID is the key to join both tables
- Code in the Items table include main product code (abc123456) and variants (-111-01). I need to group the lines by main product code only
- Quantity I need comes from Warehouse table and it equals "QuantityInStock - QuantityOnOrder - QuantityOnOrder2 - QuantityOnOrder3 - QuantityOnOrder4". Using this we get abc123456 (comes in two variants in Items table with ItemId 1111 and 2222) and Quantity is equal 8 minus 1 minus 0 minus 1 minus 0 for 1111, and 3 minus 0 minus 0 minus 0 minus 0 for 2222 which together gives 9

This is probably the worst explanation ever, so I hope there is someone that can understand it.

Please help.

Comment: Is the main product code always in the same pattern and can you always guarantee that you only need to match on the first 9 left characters?

Comment: Yes. I apologise I should have mentioned that. It will always be 9 characters. I'm guessing you think about LEFT(Code,9)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using standard SQL:

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(Items.Code, 9) AS ShortCode, 
  SUM(T.remaining) AS Quantity 
FROM Items
JOIN ( 
  SELECT 
    ItemID, 
    QuantityInStock - QuantityOnOrder - QuantityOnOrder2 - QuantityOnOrder3 - QuantityOnOrder4 AS remaining 
  FROM Warehouse
) AS T ON (T.ItemID = Items.ItemID)
GROUP BY LEFT(Items.Code, 9);
```

Not tested, but should work. Only potential issue is that you use uppercase letters in your table and column names, so you might have to enclose all table and column names in backticks (`) or square brackets depending on your DB server.

EDIT: If you want to filter those with less than a certain number of pieces left, just add:

```
HAVING SUM(T.remaining) > xxx
```

Where `xxx` is the minimum quantity you want

Comment: No, `Quantity`, which is the sum of all remaining counts for that ShortCode. If you filter on `remaining`, then you will remove individual items, but not groups that share the same ShortCode.

Comment: OK I understand now. However HAVING Quantity > xxx is giving me this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: Are you adding the `HAVING Quantity > xxx` after GROUP BY, but before the semicolon at the end?

Comment: GROUP BY LEFT(Items.Code, 9)
HAVING Quantity > 5
;

Comment: use: `HAVING SUM(T.remaining) > 5`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you can always count on matching the first 9 characters of the Code column then the following query should work.

```
/// note that the SUM method may return a negative (-) number
SELECT LEFT(I.[Code], 9) AS 'ShortCode', SUM([QuantityInStock] - [QuantityOnOrder] - [QuantityOnOrder2] - [QuantityOnOrder3] - [QuantityOnOrder4]) AS 'Quantity'
FROM [dbo].[Warehouse] AS W
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Items] AS I ON I.[ItemId] = W.[ItemId]
GROUP BY LEFT(I.[Code], 9)
```

Comment: One more thing though - How do I get the calculation of QuantityInStock minus all the QuantityOn Order columns into the code?

Comment: No probs, but I wasn't sure on how to calculate the Quantity field so @Jonhoo's answer might be more in accordance to what you need.

Comment: How could I use 'Quantity' to filter out records with less then specified number of pieces?

Comment: Updated my answer to also include instructions on how to limit this.